# SwiftUI sidebar list does not register first click

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, navigationlink

Using SwiftUI, I have a sidebar navigation in a **Mac app** to change views. Clicking an item in the sidebar changes the view on the right. However, when the app is launched, the sidebar `List` does not register the first click. It takes two clicks to select an item. Afterwards, the sidebar behaves as it should and only requires one click to change the view.

How can I fix this initial launch issue with the `List`?

[image: sidebar navigation]

```
import SwiftUI

struct DetailView: View {

    var selection: String

    var body: some View {
        containedView()
    }

    private func containedView() -> AnyView {
        switch selection {
        case " Apple":
            return AnyView(AppleView())
        case " Banana":
            return AnyView(BananaView())
        case " Coconut":
            return AnyView(CoconutView())
        default:
            return AnyView(Text("Some view here").frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity))
        }
    }
}

struct SidebarView: View {

    let items = [" Apple", " Banana", " Coconut", " Cherry", " Peanut", " Peach", " Tomato", " Bread", " Pizza", " Broccoli", " Kiwi", " Cheese", " Watermelon"]

    var body: some View {
        List(items, id: \.self) { item in
            NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(selection: item)) {
                Text("\(item)")
            }
        }
        .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            SidebarView()
            DetailView(selection: " Apple")
        }
        .frame(height: 300)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is needed to add selection for List, like below

```
@State var current = Set<String>()
var body: some View {
    List(items, id: \.self, selection: $current) { item in
        NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(selection: item)) {
            Text(item)
        }
    }
    .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why the `selection` binding is needed for `List` to work properly in a Mac app? This isn't needed in an iOS app.

Comment: Well, and there is no SidebarListStyle() on iOS. It was only assumption, but I've got a mind that it needs to synchronise initial selections for Sidebar-Details.